# image cropping and resizing

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to crop image using jquery ... I am getting right cropped image for one image but am not getting for second image ... here is code I am following

```
$("#cropimage").click(function() {
    var img_full_div_top = parseInt($(".full_single_image").position().top);
    var img_full_div_left = parseInt($(".full_single_image").position().left);
    var crop_tool_div_left = parseInt($("#crop_tool").position().left);
    var crop_tool_div_top = parseInt($("#crop_tool").position().top);
        img_full_div_top.toFixed();
        img_full_div_left.toFixed();
        crop_tool_div_left.toFixed();
        crop_tool_div_top.toFixed();

        var crop_start_x = crop_tool_div_left-img_full_div_left;
        var crop_start_y = crop_tool_div_top-img_full_div_top;

        var crop_tool_div_width = parseInt($("#crop_tool").width());
        var crop_tool_div_height = parseInt($("#crop_tool").height());

        crop_tool_div_width.toFixed();
        crop_tool_div_height.toFixed();

        var img_name = '<?php echo $name;?>';
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('upload/cropImage'); ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {crop_start_x:crop_start_x,crop_start_y:crop_start_y,crop_tool_div_width:crop_tool_div_width,crop_tool_div_height:crop_tool_div_height,img_name:img_name },
            success : function(data){
                //window.parent.location.href = window.parent.location;
            }
        });
    });
```

the code above used to get co-ordinates and height and width of image
html code is follows

```
<div class="full_single_image">

<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/directory/uploads/<?php echo $name; ?> " id="size_of_image">

<div id="crop_tool" style="display: block;"><div class="dragimageTo"><p>  Drag or Resize Image</p></div></div>

</div>
<button type="button"  id="cropimage" img_name="hi">Crop</button>
```

onclick button it will go to above function

and image saving code in php is follows

```
$src_x = $_POST['crop_start_x'];
$src_y = $_POST['crop_start_y'];
$height = $_POST['crop_tool_div_height'];
$width = $_POST['crop_tool_div_width'];
$img_name = $_POST['img_name'];
$location = './directory/uploads/'.$img_name;
$target = './directory/cropped/'.$img_name;
$src_w = $width + $src_x;
$src_h = $height + $src_y;
$newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);

$source=imagecreatefromjpeg($location);

imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,$src_x,$src_y,$width,$height,$src_w,$src_h);
imagejpeg($newImage,$target);
```

[cropped image click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8x0O.jpg)

[what am trying to crop click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSEkM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

sorry finally i got answer

uploaded files size must be equal to croping image

```
$source=imagecreatefromjpeg($location);

imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,$src_x,$src_y,$width,$height,$src_w,$src_h);
```

here **height and width** of `$source != $src_w , $src_h`